# Fill column with value in a pandas Series

Tags: pandas

I have the product of a `pandas` `groupby().sum()` as follows:

```
DTO  ZONA 
1    1         4839
     2         7347
     3         1945
     4         2248
     5         9395
     99999      575
2    1         8739
     2         7436
     3         5528
     4         7490
```

Now I would like to get to:

```
DTO  ZONA 
1    1         4839
1    2         7347
1    3         1945
1    4         2248
1    5         9395
1    99999      575
2    1         8739
2    2         7436
2    3         5528
2    4         7490
```

This *must* have been asked before, but I lack the concepts to search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `pandas` option that sparsifies a `pd.MultiIndex`.  You can turn it off with the option named `display.multi_sparse`.  You can see other options [**here**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

---

```
print(s)

DTO  ZONA 
1    1        4839
     2        7347
     3        1945
     4        2248
     5        9395
     99999     575
2    1        8739
     2        7436
     3        5528
     4        7490
dtype: int64
```

---

You can set `pandas` options temporarily with `pd.options_context`

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(s)

DTO  ZONA 
1    1        4839
1    2        7347
1    3        1945
1    4        2248
1    5        9395
1    99999     575
2    1        8739
2    2        7436
2    3        5528
2    4        7490
dtype: int64
```

---

If you want to set the option permanently:

```
pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```